# git not responding to my rails vendor/plugins directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, plugins, paperclip

My git works fine in my app, except it doesn't respond to my `vendor/plugins/paperclip` directory. I can make a change in `vendor/plugins/whatever` and git status will show it, but not in `vendor/plugins/paperclip`. My .gitignore file only gas log* and `public/system` in it. I'm pretty stumped...searched google & asked in IRC, but nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might re-read http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore , then check for the presence of alternate .gitignore files.

```
find . -name .gitignore
```

from the project root might reveal something.